# What's the purpose of "only" here?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), Frank says to Sidney about guitarist:

> Frank: That's a lollipop, that boy. The kid's **only** great.

What's the purpose of "only" here?

Comment: Quite difficult to tell from this fragment. It seems to be part of a conversation in which a lot is being omitted. *Possibly* it is saying that the kid has no other characteristics besides greatness. Or possibly it is saying that nobody besides the kid is great. Or possibly it is saying that "that" from the first sentence is the only thing the kid has that is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*“Rat Queens is a comic,” she said, “and it's **only the best thing since sliced bread.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it%27s+only+the+best+thing+since+sliced+bread%22) That's an example of the relatively common "facetious reversal" used for emphasis in relaxed conversational contexts.

Compare colloquial [*He's **only** gone and done it.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22He%27s%20only%20gone%20and%20done%20it%22)

---

TL;DR: In such contexts, ***only*** is an "intensifier" equivalent to, for example, ***very, really, actually***.